# Contar número de páginas PDF com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

Estou gerando um arquivo PDF com relatórios gerados através do PHP.

No arquivo PDF são gerados um número x de relatórios e cada relatório tem um número y de páginas. Preciso saber se esse número y e par ou ímpar, se for ímpar preciso adicionar uma página em branco.

O relatório está sendo gerado em uma View do Laravel assim:

```
    @foreach($relatorio as $r)

    <div class="page-break">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Mauris vel metus dui. 
    Etiam aliquam convallis nisi eu hendrerit. 
    Fusce tincidunt molestie aliquam. 
    Pellentesque porta nunc sit amet est accumsan luctus. 
    Cras fringilla pellentesque nulla at convallis...

    </div>

    @endforeach
```

Estou fazendo a quebra de página ao final de cada relatório com o a classe CSS:

```
.page-break{
   page-break-after:always;
}
```

Pensei em usar JavaScript para contar quantas páginas são geradas dentro da `div .page-break` mas não tenho nenhuma ideia de como fazer essa contagem

Pensei também em contar o total de páginas e dividir pela quantidade de relatórios mas também não sei como fazer. 
Obs: todos os relatórios tem a mesma quantidade de páginas.

Comment: O que vc usa como feramenta em PHP para criar o documento? TCPDF?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso resolve. Estou supondo que o `for` em `$relatorio` seja para listar as paginas, sendo cada `$r`uma pagina.

```
@foreach($relatorio as $i=>$r)
    @if( $i==count($relatorio)-1 && ($i % 2)==1)
        <div class="page-break">
            pagina vazia vai aqui, ou seja la como for a pagina vazia.
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach;
```

Comment: O `foreach` não é para listar as  páginas, mas para listar cada relatório. O relatório pode ter um número variável de páginas

Comment: Entendi, mas entao posta como voce cria ou le as paginas, por que nao tem como ninguem aqui saber o o que tem dentro da variavel `$r`, olhando para  o codigo que passou pode ser um texto ou um objeto bem complexo, e como é `@foreach($relatorio` no singular achei que `$relatorio` ja fosse o array com as paginas.

Comment: Mas ela deixou claro na pergunta que cada relatório poderia ter mais de uma página, por conta do tamanho do texto.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira acredito que o conteúdo do relatório não fará diferença na contagem das páginas.